# Why at different points in time the cost estimate of the query plan using EXPLAIN is different in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, explain

My application has several tests that calculate and return a query plan using EXPLINE. But besides them, there are also about 200 different tests with database operations. And if some of these tests  pass before the query plan test (usually adding new records to the table), then the plan's estimated cost increases.

What could be the reason for the increase in the cost estimate? There is no garbage from old tests, all tables are cleared after each test, and before executing a new one, the necessary data for a particular test is inserted into the clean tables

Comment: Different data, different statistics

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
That's just the point that the data coincide. For each test, the same data is inserted and records from previous tests are deleted. Therefore, the expected behavior is that the query plan must also be the same every time, regardless of the order in which the tests are run.

Comment: Do you update the statistics after inserting the test data using `analyze table_name` ?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
No. Is it necessary to do this?

Comment: It is necessary to ANALYZE it yourself if you want predictable results.  Otherwise it is a matter of luck whether autovac has run and finished between when you load the data and when you query the data.

Comment: @jjanes
This doesn't work for me. I added ANALYZE table_name after each inserting test data. But it steel return another result as I expected. And the cost is always higher. Maybe postgres has some kind of caches from which the analyzer takes obsolete values that are not updated by ANALYZE?